# Typescript property derived from other properties

Tags: typescript, class, properties

I have a simple class in Typescript which has an `id` and `name` properties. I want to have a third property called `displayText` which concatenates these other two properties.

I know in c# it would look like the following, what's the equivalent syntax in Typescript?

```
public string DisplayText => Id + " - " + Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [accessor](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp):

```
class Person {
    constructor(public name: string, public id: string) {}
    get displayText() { return this.id + " - " + this.name }
}

let p = new Person("Name", "Id")
console.log(p.displayText)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGn6w6EALogK7DEqIAUADmQEYgCWw0aYAtvAFzQlELNAHMANNAbM20FgBN+g4SICUWAL658I+MWhyWEOuACeAFXgAPYjTWZoiXWUQZiAC0MA6edADU0ACJoAFpAv2h3L04eaE1NbBBdSWgAXg54AHc4JFQ0GgCAOW54AIkAgEk5AJVsQjRURM8QFBF6TwMjUwtrFSA)